# Qt Windows Deployment: Application does not start

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt5.5

I have written a c++ application using Qt 5.5.1 compiled with msvc-12.0. Now I want to deploy the Application and I'm using the Qt Windows Deployment tool (windeployqt.exe). Using `windeployqt` produces a whole bunch of dlls that my application requires and it also creates a platforms directory where it copies `qwindows.dll`. From another stack-overflow post I saw that `qminimal.dll` might also be required and I have manually copied it as well in the platforms directory. In addition to the dlls pointed out by `windeployqt`, my application uses Boost Python libraries so I manually copied the dlls for `boost-python/boost-system` and the `python27.dll` libraries.
Now when I start the application on a different windows computer, the program simply doesn't start. Also it does not give any kind of error messages about missing dlls. I have installed the msvc-12.0 x64 redistributable packages. I used Dependency walker's profile option and I see that there are no missing dlls but the Application exits with code 1 (0x1) after it gets started.
Any ideas on where the problem might be. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not mentioned any plugin dll. Did windeployqt copy them to?

Comment: Edit: windeployqt copied `bearer, iconengines, imageformats, translations`.

Comment: Does that system have python 2.7 installed? Including just the dll is not enough.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala I did not have python installed in that system. Installing python 2.7 resolved the issue and application is starting. Thanks a lot.. You saved my day.. If you could post this as the answer I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mostly likely reason was that Python 2.7 was not installed. Simply copying `python27.dll` file does not suffice.